# I want to delete record from GridView.Before to this ask for confirmation like "Are you sure to delete?"

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to delete record from GridView.Before to this ask for confirmation like "Are you sure to delete?"

I used command field in GridView,

```
<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
```

I wrote a function in javascript

```
function confirm_Delete()
{
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to Remove this Record!");

    if (r == true)
    {
        alert("Record Deleted");
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How I will call this on delete click.
Kindly suggest !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't achieve this using the command field, you have to make a template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" 
             OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to Remove this Record!');">
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

It will behave the same way you are doing currently with the Command Field.

Answer (score 5):

I would do the same as @Muhammad told you, and at the server side code for deleting I would also register an script for showing the "Record Deleted" message, as follows;

```
public void MethodForDeletingARecord()
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, base.GetType(), "RecordDeletedMessage", "javascript:alert('Record Deleted');", true);
}
```

Comment: the margarrete copy/paste your code just to vote him self. I have report him because did the same to me.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can achieve this for commandfield

Assuming it would be the first column, [Found Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428868.aspx)

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // reference the Delete LinkButton
        LinkButton db = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];

        db.OnClientClick = "javascript:return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete?');"
    }
}
```

Comment: if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView.Columns["clm_Delete"].Index) is how I varify that the delete button was clicked in the delete column if you want to adjust it to work with something besides column 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Attributes.Add("onclick", "return Conformation();");
    }
}
```